# How to get the pdf file lists folder by folder?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Now i am currently working on pdf reader application, i can read all the pdf files which are present inside the application by using the following code,

```
NSArray *userDocuments = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSURL *docementsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[userDocuments lastObject]];
NSArray *documentsURLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:docementsURL
                                                       includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
                                                                          options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                                            error:nil];

NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *urls = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSArray *bundledResources = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLsForResourcesWithExtension:@"pdf" subdirectory:nil];
documentsURLs = [documentsURLs arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:bundledResources];

for (NSURL *docURL in documentsURLs)
{
    NSString *title = [[docURL lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    [names addObject:title];
    [urls setObject:docURL forKey:title];
}

documents = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
urlsByName = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:urls];
```

But my problem is to read the pdf file folder by folder and store that in to separate arrays,
my folder structure is like the following image,

[image]

Any help regarding this will be appreciated..

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images" ofType:nil]; as image is the name of folder.

Comment: @BuntyMadan it is not working, more over it is not an array, it's a string class..

Comment: as with this we can get the path of specific folder after use URLsForResourcesWithExtension for pdf files. not tried on Xcode just Idea Sharing with you

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can create bundles instead of folders
and then get all bundles and files inside them

something like this

```
NSArray *bundleArr = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle" inDirectory:nil];
NSLog(@"pdfs in bundle %@ is my class is %@",[bundleArr objectAtIndex:0],[[bundleArr objectAtIndex:0]class]);


for (int i=0; i<[bundleArr count]; i++) {
    NSString *myBundleStr=[bundleArr objectAtIndex:i];
    NSBundle *myBundle = [[NSBundle alloc]initWithPath:[bundleArr objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSArray *pdfPaths = [myBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];
    NSLog(@"\n\nPDF in bundle  is %@",pdfPaths);

}
```

Comment: Sorry for late replay,, its getting crash something like ` -[NSBundle _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f80650`

Comment: that is i was saying, You have to make a bundle of PDF files and then run this code

Comment: if i create as a bundle the i can't read the selected pdf file. from the listed table..(refer updated screen shot).

Comment: previously i have accessed like ` NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[documents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"pdf"];`